# Creating IFS formula in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am creating a worksheet for tracking odds in MMA fights for betting purposes. I have a system that includes multiple data points but my starting point is what I call my base unit (to which I then add and subtract based on certain criteria which is not exactly part of this question).

There are certain odds ranges that I use to get my base unit (see below):

```
-900 or lower = 5 units
-300 - -400 = 4 units
+100 - +122 = 3 units
+123 - +150 = 2 units
+151 - +186 = 1 Unit
```

I enter the odds in my first cell column which has basic conditional formating: Green if the number is in one of those ranges. Red if not. I would like to create a formula that only applies a base unit for the green ranges. I have been reading about multiple if statements but I cannot figure out how to build these specific ranges into one IFS formula. Ideally if the number falls anywhere outside of these ranges it would already by red and the base unit column can be 0. If it falls in one of the ranges I would like the associated base unit to be populated into that cell. Sorry if this is confusing I feel like I get it in my head but typing it out makes it jumbled.

I am happy to clarify anything. Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: What if it is in the range `-299 --> +99` or one of your other unspecified ranges?

Answer (score 1):

IFS:

```
=IFS(A1<=-900,5,AND(A1>=-400,A1<=-300),4,AND(A1>=100,A1<=122),3,AND(A1>=123,A1<=150),2,AND(A1>=151,A1<=186),1,TRUE,"")
```

Comment: Scott Craner you are a god amongst men! Thank you so much!